# Unity Scripts Working Fine in Editor, But not in Build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build

I am a Newbie in Unity. I recently created a script that disables buttons in a scene until a condition is satisfied *(For a Level Selection Menu, to disable all levels until the player completes previous levels)*.
But the problem is - My script works fine when I run the game in **Editor**, but when I **Build and then Run** the Game, Script fails to * ***Work Correctly*** * .

Here is that script -

```
// Import required Modules

public class ButtonGatherer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Button> buttons;
    public static int OpenLevels;
    void Start()
    {   if (OpenLevels == 0){
        OpenLevels = int.Parse(File.ReadAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "Data.gokartgo"));} //Reads Data from a file

        GameObject[] btn = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("button");
        for (int i = 0; i < btn.Length; i++){
            buttons.Add(btn[i].GetComponent<Button>());
        }
        Debug.Log("Variable OpenLevels : "+OpenLevels);
        for(int i = OpenLevels; i < buttons.Count; i++) { 
            buttons[i].interactable = false;
            Debug.Log("Var i : " + i +",     So Locked Level : " + buttons[i]); //Used This To debug and get values for variable i
        }

    }
}
```

I Have Also attached of the Screenshot of Debug Message That I Get -
When Running in Editor - 
[ScreenShot of Debug Trace when running in Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmQVd.png)

When Running After Building *(Development Build)* -
[Screenshot of Debug Trace When Running After Building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz3j9.png)

Please Help ....

Edit : I Searched Unity Documentations and Forums but found Nothing

Comment: Does your `int OpenLevels` need to be static? Also are there several instances of ButtonGatherer across the lifetime of the build?

Comment: Could you describe what `Script fails to * Work Correctly * .` means exactly? In both screenshots `OpenLevels` is not `0` and values seem to be set so what exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue probably lies in the line

```
OpenLevels = int.Parse(File.ReadAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "Data.gokartgo"));}
```

There is a missing path separator so this results in a path looking like e.g.

```
                                     | This is now a file that doesn't even 
                                     | lie within your apps data!
                                     V 
\root\applications\yourapp\persistentDataData.gokartgo
```

On most devices such an access is not allowed!

You would need a `/` or `\` between them.

---

But **do not** use `+ "/"` see below!

Long story short: **Never** use `+ ""` or `+ "/"` for system file paths as they might be incorrect depending on the target platform (e.g. Windows `\`, Unix `/`).

Rather use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which automatically inserts the correct path separator according to your platform:

```
OpenLevels = int.Parse(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Data.gokartgo"));
```

---

If the issue you are talking about is the button numbers you are getting note that for `FindGameObjectsWithTag` it might not be guaranteed that the results are always returned in the same order.

Comment: First of all,**Thanks for help** . Tried this But didn't work for me. Still the same problem :-(

Comment: does the according file exist on your device?

Comment: Yes, it existed. I fixed it. **Actually The Sequence of buttons was wrong** after I Build the file. As You said `FindGameObjectWithTag` not guaranteed the result *in same order*, I Fixed it by just adding Buttons Manually instead of using `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("button")` to get buttons, and it worked . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your script works fine in the editor then the data file path might be the problem. Try this code and see if the problem still exists.

```
public class ButtonGatherer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Button> buttons;
    public static int OpenLevels;
    void Start()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("OpenLevels"))
        {
            OpenLevels = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("OpenLevels");
        }
        else
        {
            OpenLevels = 0;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("OpenLevels", 0)
        }

        GameObject[] btn = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("button");
        for (int i = 0; i < btn.Length; i++)
        {
            buttons.Add(btn[i].GetComponent<Button>());
        }
        Debug.Log("Variable OpenLevels : " + OpenLevels);

        for (int i = OpenLevels; i < buttons.Count; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].interactable = false;
            Debug.Log("Var i : " + i + ",     So Locked Level : " + buttons[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Thanks For Help*,  This Too Didn't Work in my case.